# Elasticsearch - query primary and secondary attribute with different terms

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I'm using elasticsearch to query data that originally was exported out of several relational databases that had a lot of redundencies. I now want to perform queries where I have a primary attribute and one or more secondary attributes that should match. I tried using a bool query with a must term and a should term, but that doesn't seem to work for my case, which may look like this:

Example:

I have a document with `fullname` and `street name` of a user and I want to search for similiar users in different indices. So the best match for my query should be the best match on `fullname` and best match on `streetname` field. But since the original data has a lot of redundencies and inconsistencies the field `fullname` (which I manually created out of fields name1, name2, name3) may contain the same name multiple times and it seems that elasticsearch ranks a double match in a must field higher than a match in a should attribute.

That means, I want to query for `John Doe` `Back Street` with the following sample data:

```
{
    "fullname" : "John Doe John and Jane",
    "street" : "Main Street"

}
{
    "fullname" : "John Doe",
    "street" : "Back Street"

}
```

Long story short, I want to query for a main attribute `fullname - John Doe` and secondary attribute `street - Back Street` and want the second document to be the best match and not the first because it contains `John` multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulation of relevance in Elasticsearch is not the easiest part. Score calculation is based on three main parts:

- Term frequency
- Inverse document frequency
- Field-length norm

Shortly:

- the often the term occurs in field, the MORE relevant is
- the often the term occurs in entire index, the LESS relevant is
- the longer the term is, the MORE relevant is

I recommend you to read below materials:

- [What Is Relevance?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html)
- [Theory Behind Relevance Scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html)
- [Controlling Relevance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/controlling-relevance.html) and subpages

If in general, in your case, result of `fullname` is more important than from `street` you can boost importance of the first one. Below you have example code base on my working code:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "john doe",
      "fields": [
        "fullname^10",
        "street"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this example result from `fullname` is ten times (`^10`) much important than result from `street`. You can try to manipulate the boost or use other ways to control relevance but as I mentioned at the beginning - it is not the easiest way and everything depends on your particular situation. Mostly because of "inverse document frequency" part which considers terms from entire index - each next added document to index will probably change the score of the same search query.

I know that I did not answer directly but I hope to helped you to understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems it's really not that simple as I previously thought. However I think that boosting fields will provide a good workaround for now.